# Discord.js - issue with connecting to voice channels

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm on discord.js v12.2.0 and node v12.13.0.

My code:

```
const yts = require("yt-search");
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const queue = [];
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { prefix, token } = require("./config.json");

client.on("ready", function () {
  console.log("ready!");
});

client.on("message", async function (msg) {
  if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix) || msg.author.bot) return;
  const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(" ");
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  if (command == "play") {
    if (msg.member.voice.channel) {
      const r = await yts(args.join(" "));
      queue.push(ytdl(r.videos[0].url));
      if (queue.length == 1) {
// I believe the error is right here
        const connection = await msg.member.voice.channel.join();
        play();
        msg.channel.send("Began stream");
        function play() {
          const dispatcher = connection.play(queue[0]);
          dispatcher.on("finish", function () {
            dispatcher.destroy();
            if (queue.length != 0) {
              queue.shift();
              play();
            }
          });
        }
      }
    } else {
      msg.channel.send("Error (make sure you are in voice)");
    }
  } else if (command == "pause") {
    if (bot.voice.channel && message.member.voice.channel) {
      dispatcher.pause();
      msg.channel.send("Paused stream");
    } else {
      msg.channel.send("Error (make sure both you and the bot are in voice)");
    }
  } else if (command == "resume") {
    if (bot.voice.channel && message.member.voice.channel) {
      dispatcher.resume();
      msg.channel.send("Resumed stream");
    } else {
      msg.channel.send("Error (make sure both you and the bot are in voice)");
    }
  } else if (command == "stop") {
    if (bot.voice.channel && message.member.voice.channel) {
      dispatcher.destroy();
      msg.channel.send("Stopped stream");
    } else {
      msg.channel.send("Error (make sure both you and the bot are in voice)");
    }
  } else {
    msg.channel.send("Error (check command)");
  }
});

client.login(token);
```

throws error:

(node:12512) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [VOICE_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT]: Connection not established within 15 seconds.
at VoiceConnection.authenticateFailed (C:\Users\Robbie\Desktop\bot\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\VoiceConnection.js:304:26)
at C:\Users\Robbie\Desktop\bot\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\VoiceConnection.js:325:61
at Timeout. (C:\Users\Robbie\Desktop\bot\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js:83:7)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
(node:12512) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12512) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some general steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve these issues:

Update Dependencies: Ensure that all the dependencies, including "@discordjs/voice" and other related packages, are up to date. Sometimes, outdated dependencies can cause compatibility issues.

Check Socket Handling: Review the code that manages socket connections and ensure that sockets are correctly opened, closed, and handled. Make sure that sockets are not closed prematurely.

Error Handling: Check the error handling in your code. Properly handle and catch errors to prevent unhandled rejections.

Debugging: If the error persists, try to add more logging and debugging statements to trace the flow of the code and identify where the issue might be occurring.

Discord API Status: Occasionally, issues might arise due to problems on Discord's end. Check the status of the Discord API to see if there are any ongoing outages or incidents.

Discord Support: If you've exhausted all other options and the issue persists, consider reaching out to the Discord API support team for further assistance.

Comment: User should read this carfully. 
It seems like this answer is generate via AI tools like `ChatGpt` or `Google Bard`

Comment: Nope sometimes it could be from packages or so